# Share variables between stages (running in different agent pools) in Azure DevOps Pipelines (no inline script)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've been trying to share variables from one stage to another in azure pipelines, I've found information/other posts about it, but all using the inline method and no reference to multiple agent pools. My pipeline uses 3 different agent pool (one for each stage) this due to security compliance.

The flow (currently working fine) goes like this (Only one of the 2nd stages is run based on specific conditions).

1. Stage 1 - validate initial pipeline variables.
2. Stage2a - Only run if stage 1 finished successfully and if condition if met.
3. Stage 2b - Only run if stage 1 finished successfully and if condition if met.
4. Stage 2c - Only run if stage 1 finished successfully and if condition if met.

A new request has been raised to add a third stage with a different agent pool that should be run only after any of the previous stages (2a or 2b or 2c) is completed (is this even posible to validate upong successfull of any of the previous 3 different stages). Any of these stages produce the same variables which I need to passed onto stage 3, and here is the issue. I've bee trying to figure it how to make it work but so far I have had no luck.

Below is a example of my pipeline. The top part are the last lines of the powershell script (newdeploy.ps1) where the output variables are being declared

```
####### OUTPUT VARIABLES    ##########
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=location;isOutput=true]$location"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=state;isOutput=true]$state"
##########################################

- stage: stage2a
    condition: succeeded('stage1')
    dependsOn: stage1
    jobs:
      - job: job_stage2a
        condition: not(contains(variables.terrain, 'private'))
        continueOnError: false
        pool: 'agentpool2'
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'public_task'
          inputs:
            filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts/newdeploy.ps1'
            arguments: >
              -terrain ${env:TERRAIN}
              -value ${env:VALUE}
            failOnStderr: true
            showWarnings: true
            workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts/'


- stage: stage3
    condition: succeeded('stage1')
    dependsOn: stage1
    variables:
    - name: location
      value: $[ stageDependencies.stage2a.job_stage2a.outputs['public_task.location'] ]
    - name: state
      value: $[ stageDependencies.stage2a.job_stage2a.outputs['public_task.state'] ]
    jobs:
      - job: job_stage3
        continueOnError: false
        pool: 'agentpool3'
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          displayName: 'registry'
          inputs:
            filePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts/registry.ps1'
            arguments: >
              -location variables.location
              -state variables.state
              -terrain ${env:TERRAIN}
              -value ${env:VALUE}
            failOnStderr: true
            showWarnings: true
            workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Scripts/Ops/DOG/'
```

As you can see on stage3 I added the output variables from stage2a but from there I'm not sure on how to proceed. Firstly, some post mention to do this within the stage declaration but some other mention to do it within the job declaration, which one is correct? Secondly, how should I pass them to the other script (registry.ps1), I tried to pass them as arguments but within the script those 2 variables are empty or the actual string is being printed (variables.location or variables.state is what I get, not the actual value). Lastly, is this request even possible? to share a variable from a previous stage ran in a different agent pool ?